# np array rows with unique elements

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider the numpy array below.   I'd hoping to find a fast way to remove rows not having 4 distinct values.

```
import numpy as np

D = np.array([[2, 3, 6, 7],
              [2, 4, 3, 4],
              [4, 9, 0, 1],
              [5, 5, 2, 5],
              [7, 5, 4, 8],
              [7, 5, 4, 7]])
```

In the small sample array show, the output should be:

```
D = np.array([[2, 3, 6, 7],
              [4, 9, 0, 1],
              [7, 5, 4, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
In [94]: s = np.sort(D,axis=1)

In [95]: D[(s[:,:-1] == s[:,1:]).sum(1) ==0]
Out[95]: 
array([[2, 3, 6, 7],
       [4, 9, 0, 1],
       [7, 5, 4, 8]])
```

Alternatively -

```
In [107]: D[~(s[:,:-1] == s[:,1:]).any(1)]
Out[107]: 
array([[2, 3, 6, 7],
       [4, 9, 0, 1],
       [7, 5, 4, 8]])
```

Or -

```
In [112]: D[(s[:,:-1] != s[:,1:]).all(1)]
Out[112]: 
array([[2, 3, 6, 7],
       [4, 9, 0, 1],
       [7, 5, 4, 8]])
```

With pandas -

```
In [121]: import pandas as pd

In [122]: D[pd.DataFrame(D).nunique(1)==4]
Out[122]: 
array([[2, 3, 6, 7],
       [4, 9, 0, 1],
       [7, 5, 4, 8]])
```

Comment: As a relative newcomer to Numpy, I appreciate the multiple approaches.

Comment: Your solutions worked great and were very fast.  But,  I'm puzzled by the 1 argument used in .sum(1),  any(1), and .all(1).  In each of these, I thought a singular argument would have to be the array, in these cases, s.   Could this be explained?

Comment: @user109387 Those are just `axis` arguments. So, those are equivalent to `.sum(axis=1)` and so on. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  Its just that I thought the array name argument was mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

A working answer with np.unique

I found no way to use the axis keyword in np.unique to get rid of the list compression, perhaps someone can help?

```
D[np.array([np.max(np.unique(_,return_counts=True)[-1]) for _ in D])==1]
```